# pandas time series and pickling

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing a very strange problem using pandas.

I have a panda time series, that is fine and working. I pickle it with python standard tool, but when I want to unpickle it back, pandas fail to rebuild the object, pretexting that the index is wrong.

Is there a problem with pickling pandas data structure? A prefered way to do it? Is there anything wrong with the way I plan to do it?

Here are the details:

I have some time series, called data, that after some processing, would like to keep as a pickle file, for reuse speedup. My time series look like this:

```
sample_time
2013-06-03 21:55:40    0.553846
2013-06-03 22:13:25    0.569231
...
2013-07-09 16:55:00    0.430769
2013-07-09 16:57:45    0.430769
2013-07-09 16:59:44    0.384615
Name: fill, Length: 11550
```

I pickle the Series object like this:

```
pickle.dump(data,open("pickle_file","w"))
```

and then try to reload it later:

```
data_back=pickle.load(open("pickle_file",'r'))
```

I then get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/antoine/velib/code/project_tools.py", line 197, in <module>
    test()  
  File "/home/antoine/velib/code/project_tools.py", line 172, in test
    data_back=p_l(open("test_dump",'r'))
  File "/home/antoine/program/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/home/antoine/program/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/home/antoine/program/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1217, in load_build
    setstate(state)
  File "/home/antoine/program/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2063, in __setstate__
    placement=self.axes[0].get_indexer(items))
  File "/home/antoine/program/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1259, in get_indexer
    raise InvalidIndexError('Reindexing only valid with uniquely'
pandas.core.index.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Pandas refuse to rebuild the Series, finding that the index might not be unique.
But my time series datetime index is guaranteed to be unique. Proof: if I build a serie from my data's index, I find no duplicate:

I make a new serie containing only the index of my data Series.

```
data_index=pd.DataFrame(data=data.index)
data_index["dup"]=data_index.duplicated()

data_index
              sample_time    dup
0     2013-06-03 21:55:40  False
1     2013-06-03 22:13:25  False
2     2013-06-03 22:19:21  False
...                   ...    ...
11547 2013-07-09 16:55:00  False
11548 2013-07-09 16:57:45  False
11549 2013-07-09 16:59:44  False

[11550 rows x 2 columns]
```

So for me there is no problem with the time index, it is unique.
The data time serie looks legal, as it exists at the first time. But during the process of pickling and unpickling, pandas refuses to build the time serie back.

Could that be a bug?

Comment: what version pandas?

Comment: especially if you are crossing versions you should use the built in pickle support: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#io-pickle

Comment: there was a bug (fixed in master), see here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7794; but only shows up if their are duplicates

Comment: pandas.__version__ gives me 0.14.0 and I pickle and unpickle two lines of code later in the same piece of code, using the same versions of pandas and pickle

Comment: show data.index.is_unique

Comment: Surprisingly data.index.is_unique returns False

Comment: so u are hitting that bug. you can update to master (0.15 coming soon as well). usually duplicates in an index just make things harder to deal with. you can do: s.loc[Series(s.index).duplicated()] to find them (and just invert the index to select the non duplicates)

Comment: You were right, I've just upgraded Pandas to 0.14.1 and using build-in df.to_pickle() and pd.read_pickle() functions, it now works fine. Thank you for getting me out of the hole. Wanna answer the question so I can mark it as the answer to my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their was a bug present in 0.14.0, fixed in master (0.15.0), expecting release in early Oct 2014, see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7794).

Essentially trying to pickle a pandas object with a non-unique index that ONLY had a single dtype (e.g. a Series or a DataFrame only composed of floats), would fail on reconstruction because of some assumptions in the reconstruction code.

The fix is to either use master/0.15.0. (I believe 0.14.1 works as well), or to make your pandas object have a unique index.